# Accessing JSON dictionary with nested strings

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to read some data from the Eurostat server. I deserialize the string returned by the server using the Newtonsoft library:

```
Product product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(responseText);
```

The full JSON string is:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "label": "Production from aquaculture excluding hatcheries and nurseries (from 2008 onwards)",
  "href": "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/fish_aq2a?precision=1&species=SAL&aquaenv=SEA&fishreg=0&fishreg=10&fishreg=27&fishreg=5&fishreg=9&fishreg=37&fishreg=34&fishreg=NSP&fishreg=4&fishreg=1&unit=EUR&unit=EUR_T&unit=TLW&aquameth=CAG",
  "source": "Eurostat",
  "updated": "2017-10-10",
  "status": {
    "0": ":",
    "3": ":",
    "5": ":",
    "6": ":",
    "7": ":",
    "13": ":",
    "14": ":",
    "15": ":",
    "17": ":",
    "18": ":",
    "19": ":",
    "20": ":",
    "21": ":",
    "22": ":",
    "23": ":",
    "24": ":",
    "27": ":",
    "28": ":",
    "29": ":",
    "30": ":",
    "31": ":",
    "37": ":",
    "38": ":",
    "39": ":",
    "40": ":",
    "45": ":",
    "46": ":",
    "47": ":",
    "48": ":",
    "51": ":",
    "53": ":",
    "54": ":",
    "55": ":",
    "61": ":",
    "62": ":",
    "63": ":",
    "65": ":",
    "66": ":",
    "67": ":",
    "68": ":",
    "69": ":",
    "70": ":",
    "71": ":",
    "72": ":",
    "75": ":",
    "76": ":",
    "77": ":",
    "78": ":",
    "79": ":",
    "85": ":",
    "86": ":",
    "87": ":",
    "88": ":",
    "93": ":",
    "94": ":",
    "95": ":",
    "96": ":",
    "99": ":",
    "101": ":",
    "102": ":",
    "103": ":",
    "109": ":",
    "110": ":",
    "111": ":",
    "113": ":",
    "114": ":",
    "115": ":",
    "116": ":",
    "117": ":",
    "118": ":",
    "119": ":",
    "120": ":",
    "123": ":",
    "124": ":",
    "125": ":",
    "126": ":",
    "127": ":",
    "133": ":",
    "134": ":",
    "135": ":",
    "136": ":",
    "141": ":",
    "142": ":",
    "143": ":",
    "144": ":",
    "147": ":",
    "149": ":",
    "150": ":",
    "151": ":",
    "157": ":",
    "158": ":",
    "159": ":",
    "161": ":",
    "162": ":",
    "163": ":",
    "164": ":",
    "165": ":",
    "166": ":",
    "167": ":",
    "168": ":",
    "171": ":",
    "172": ":",
    "173": ":",
    "174": ":",
    "175": ":",
    "181": ":",
    "182": ":",
    "183": ":",
    "184": ":",
    "189": ":",
    "190": ":",
    "191": ":",
    "192": ":",
    "195": ":",
    "197": ":",
    "198": ":",
    "199": ":",
    "205": ":",
    "206": ":",
    "207": ":",
    "209": ":",
    "210": ":",
    "211": ":",
    "212": ":",
    "213": ":",
    "214": ":",
    "215": ":",
    "216": ":",
    "219": ":",
    "220": ":",
    "221": ":",
    "222": ":",
    "223": ":",
    "229": ":",
    "230": ":",
    "231": ":",
    "232": ":",
    "237": ":",
    "238": ":",
    "239": ":",
    "240": ":",
    "243": ":",
    "245": ":",
    "246": ":",
    "247": ":",
    "253": ":",
    "254": ":",
    "255": ":",
    "257": ":",
    "258": ":",
    "259": ":",
    "260": ":",
    "261": ":",
    "262": ":",
    "263": ":",
    "264": ":",
    "267": ":",
    "268": ":",
    "269": ":",
    "270": ":",
    "271": ":",
    "277": ":",
    "278": ":",
    "279": ":",
    "280": ":",
    "285": ":",
    "286": ":",
    "287": ":",
    "288": ":",
    "291": ":",
    "293": ":",
    "294": ":",
    "295": ":",
    "301": ":",
    "302": ":",
    "303": ":",
    "305": ":",
    "306": ":",
    "307": ":",
    "308": ":",
    "309": ":",
    "310": ":",
    "311": ":",
    "312": ":",
    "315": ":",
    "316": ":",
    "317": ":",
    "318": ":",
    "319": ":",
    "325": ":",
    "326": ":",
    "327": ":",
    "328": ":",
    "333": ":",
    "334": ":",
    "335": ":",
    "336": ":",
    "339": ":",
    "341": ":",
    "342": ":",
    "343": ":",
    "349": ":",
    "350": ":",
    "351": ":",
    "353": ":",
    "354": ":",
    "355": ":",
    "356": ":",
    "357": ":",
    "358": ":",
    "359": ":",
    "360": ":",
    "363": ":",
    "364": ":",
    "365": ":",
    "366": ":",
    "367": ":",
    "373": ":",
    "374": ":",
    "375": ":",
    "376": ":",
    "381": ":",
    "382": ":",
    "383": ":",
    "384": ":",
    "387": ":",
    "389": ":",
    "390": ":",
    "391": ":",
    "397": ":",
    "398": ":",
    "399": ":",
    "401": ":",
    "402": ":",
    "403": ":",
    "404": ":",
    "405": ":",
    "406": ":",
    "407": ":",
    "408": ":",
    "411": ":",
    "412": ":",
    "413": ":",
    "414": ":",
    "415": ":",
    "421": ":",
    "422": ":",
    "423": ":",
    "424": ":",
    "429": ":",
    "430": ":",
    "431": ":"
  },
  "extension": {
    "datasetId": "fish_aq2a",
    "lang": "EN",
    "description": null,
    "subTitle": null,
    "status": {
      "label": {
        ":": "not available"
      }
    }
  },
  "class": "dataset",
  "value": {
    "1": 3243,
    "2": 356479,
    "4": 14938,
    "8": 6007500,
    "9": 529723936.38,
    "10": 585804684.37,
    "11": 677939444.53,
    "12": 641218586.15,
    "16": 6007500,
    "25": 65367944,
    "26": 70585535,
    "32": 1851387298,
    "33": 2311910972,
    "34": 3562084862,
    "35": 3454753657,
    "36": 3739702550,
    "41": 464352749,
    "42": 514862671,
    "43": 677939445,
    "44": 641179927,
    "49": 1989,
    "50": 4501,
    "52": 3734,
    "56": 4500,
    "57": 3376.93,
    "58": 3441.86,
    "59": 4286.31,
    "60": 3946.37,
    "64": 4500,
    "73": 5354,
    "74": 4499,
    "80": 2510,
    "81": 2679,
    "82": 3791,
    "83": 3241,
    "84": 3035,
    "89": 3210,
    "90": 3334,
    "91": 4286,
    "92": 3946,
    "97": 2,
    "98": 79,
    "100": 4,
    "104": 1335,
    "105": 156865.63,
    "106": 170200,
    "107": 158164,
    "108": 162483,
    "112": 1335,
    "121": 12210,
    "122": 15691,
    "128": 737694,
    "129": 862908,
    "130": 939575,
    "131": 1065975,
    "132": 1232095,
    "137": 144654,
    "138": 154430,
    "139": 158164,
    "140": 162479,
    "145": 3243,
    "146": 356479,
    "148": 14938,
    "152": 6007500,
    "153": 529723936.38,
    "154": 585804684.37,
    "155": 677939444.53,
    "156": 641218586.15,
    "160": 6007500,
    "169": 65367944,
    "170": 70585535,
    "176": 1851387298,
    "177": 2311910972,
    "178": 3562084862,
    "179": 3454753657,
    "180": 3739702550,
    "185": 464352749,
    "186": 514862671,
    "187": 677939445,
    "188": 641179927,
    "193": 1989,
    "194": 4501,
    "196": 3734,
    "200": 4500,
    "201": 3376.93,
    "202": 3441.86,
    "203": 4286.31,
    "204": 3946.37,
    "208": 4500,
    "217": 5354,
    "218": 4499,
    "224": 2510,
    "225": 2679,
    "226": 3791,
    "227": 3241,
    "228": 3035,
    "233": 3210,
    "234": 3334,
    "235": 4286,
    "236": 3946,
    "241": 2,
    "242": 79,
    "244": 4,
    "248": 1335,
    "249": 156865.63,
    "250": 170200,
    "251": 158164,
    "252": 162483,
    "256": 1335,
    "265": 12210,
    "266": 15691,
    "272": 737694,
    "273": 862908,
    "274": 939575,
    "275": 1065975,
    "276": 1232095,
    "281": 144654,
    "282": 154430,
    "283": 158164,
    "284": 162479,
    "289": 3243,
    "290": 356479,
    "292": 14938,
    "296": 6007500,
    "297": 529723936.38,
    "298": 585804684.37,
    "299": 677939444.53,
    "300": 641218586.15,
    "304": 6007500,
    "313": 65367944,
    "314": 70585535,
    "320": 1851387298,
    "321": 2311910972,
    "322": 3562084862,
    "323": 3454753657,
    "324": 3739702550,
    "329": 464352749,
    "330": 514862671,
    "331": 677939445,
    "332": 641179927,
    "337": 1989,
    "338": 4501,
    "340": 3734,
    "344": 4500,
    "345": 3376.93,
    "346": 3441.86,
    "347": 4286.31,
    "348": 3946.37,
    "352": 4500,
    "361": 5354,
    "362": 4499,
    "368": 2510,
    "369": 2679,
    "370": 3791,
    "371": 3241,
    "372": 3035,
    "377": 3210,
    "378": 3334,
    "379": 4286,
    "380": 3946,
    "385": 2,
    "386": 79,
    "388": 4,
    "392": 1335,
    "393": 156865.63,
    "394": 170200,
    "395": 158164,
    "396": 162483,
    "400": 1335,
    "409": 12210,
    "410": 15691,
    "416": 737694,
    "417": 862908,
    "418": 939575,
    "419": 1065975,
    "420": 1232095,
    "425": 144654,
    "426": 154430,
    "427": 158164,
    "428": 162479
  },
  "dimension": {
    "aquameth": {
      "label": "aquameth",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "CAG": 0
        },
        "label": {
          "CAG": "Cages"
        }
      }
    },
    "aquaenv": {
      "label": "aquaenv",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "SEA": 0
        },
        "label": {
          "SEA": "Seawater"
        }
      }
    },
    "species": {
      "label": "species",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "SAL": 0
        },
        "label": {
          "SAL": "Atlantic salmon - Salmo salar"
        }
      }
    },
    "fishreg": {
      "label": "fishreg",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "0": 0,
          "10": 1,
          "27": 2
        },
        "label": {
          "0": "Total fishing areas",
          "10": "Marine areas",
          "27": "Atlantic, Northeast"
        }
      }
    },
    "unit": {
      "label": "unit",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "EUR": 0,
          "EUR_T": 1,
          "TLW": 2
        },
        "label": {
          "EUR": "Euro",
          "EUR_T": "Euro per tonne",
          "TLW": "Tonnes live weight"
        }
      }
    },
    "geo": {
      "label": "geo",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "ES": 0,
          "EU28": 1,
          "FR": 2,
          "IE": 3,
          "NO": 4,
          "UK": 5
        },
        "label": {
          "ES": "Spain",
          "EU28": "European Union (28 countries)",
          "FR": "France",
          "IE": "Ireland",
          "NO": "Norway",
          "UK": "United Kingdom"
        }
      }
    },
    "time": {
      "label": "time",
      "category": {
        "index": {
          "2008": 0,
          "2009": 1,
          "2010": 2,
          "2011": 3,
          "2012": 4,
          "2013": 5,
          "2014": 6,
          "2015": 7
        },
        "label": {
          "2008": "2008",
          "2009": "2009",
          "2010": "2010",
          "2011": "2011",
          "2012": "2012",
          "2013": "2013",
          "2014": "2014",
          "2015": "2015"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": [
    "aquameth",
    "aquaenv",
    "species",
    "fishreg",
    "unit",
    "geo",
    "time"
  ],
  "size": [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    3,
    3,
    6,
    8
  ]
}
```

In my Product class (MSVS 2015 C#) I have:

```
public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Extension { get; set; }
```

which works fine until I get to the "status" key, which gives an error.

The way I am getting around that is:

```
MyRow++;
MyCol = 0;
QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.Extension) + ":";
foreach (string key in product.Extension.Keys)
{
    MyRow++;
    MyCol = 0;
    dynamic myvalue = key;
    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue;


    if (key == "status")
        break;

    MyCol = 1;
    myvalue = product.Extension[key];
    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue;
}
```

Note: the MyRow & MyCol variables are for output to a spreadsheet add-in, and not relevant to the issue. I've checked a number of examples on the web, mainly on stackoverflow, but cannot manage to resolve.

Comment: *which gives an error.* ... you forgot to include the exact error and stack trace.

Comment: Your json appears mal-formed. What is `{"label":{":":"not available"}}}`

Comment: Rene: apologies, the error I get is for the variable myvalue, which then gives the error if I send myvalue to the SpreadsheetGear workbook.

The error output is:
+  $exception {"Invalid cell value type."} System.ArgumentException

Shiva: I was avoiding listing the full json but have now done so in the original post (replaced the abridged listing that was there). Please see the section:
"status":{"label":{":":"not available"}}}
the string is the original from Eurostat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `":"` JSON key it will cause some problems with using `dynamic` and duck typing.

Consider creating a strong-type for that property Like below

```
public class Extension {
    public string datasetId { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string subTitle { get; set; }
    public ExtensionStatus status { get; set; }
}

public class ExtensionStatus {
    public Dictionary<string, string> label { get; set; }
}
```

and have

```
public Extension extension { get; set; }
```

in your `Product` class

For `dimension` property, what you need to do is look for the common pattern among the nested objects.

Based on provided JSON `Dimension` would resolve to the following

```
public class Dimension {
    public DimensionDetail aquameth { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail aquaenv { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail species { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail fishreg { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail unit { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail geo { get; set; }
    public DimensionDetail time { get; set; }
}

public class DimensionDetail {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
    public Dictionary<string, int> index { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> label { get; set; }
}
```

With the property set on `Product` as

```
public Dimension dimension { get; set; }
```

That way after deserializing the string you can access it like

```
var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(responseText);
var value = product.extension.status.label[":"]; //value should equal "not available"
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Nkosi. I tried the same approach with:
"dimension",{"aquameth":{"label":"aquameth","category":{"index":{"CAG":0},"label":{"CAG":"Cages"}}}
from the same json but am unable to get it to work. I don't know how to post the set of classes I created for that - it exceeds the comment size. If I could post them maybe you could help me understand why they won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The way to read the json "dimension" component into a C# class is to create the following:

```
public class Dimension
    {
        public DimensionAquameth aquameth { get; set; }
    }
    public class DimensionAquameth
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public DimensionCategory category { get; set; }
    }

    public class DimensionCategory
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> index { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> label { get; set; }
    }
```

and then add:

```
public Dimension dimension { get; set; }
```

to the Product class.

And in the code that parses the deserialized json:

```
// Dimension field
                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension) + ":";
                // aquameth
                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension.aquameth) + ":";
                // label
                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension.aquameth.label) + ":";
                MyCol = 1;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = product.dimension.aquameth.label;
                // category
                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension.aquameth.category) + ":";
                // category index
                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension.aquameth.category.index) + ":";
                // CAG
                foreach (string key in product.dimension.aquameth.category.index.Keys)
                {
                    MyRow++;
                    MyCol = 0;
                    dynamic myvalue = key;
                    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue + ":";
                    MyCol = 1;
                    myvalue = product.dimension.aquameth.category.index[key];
                    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue;
                }

                MyRow++;
                MyCol = 0;
                QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = nameof(product.dimension.aquameth.category.label) + ":";
                // CAG
                foreach (string key in product.dimension.aquameth.category.label.Keys)
                {
                    MyRow++;
                    MyCol = 0;
                    dynamic myvalue = key;
                    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue + ":";
                    MyCol = 1;
                    myvalue = product.dimension.aquameth.category.label[key];
                    QueryOutputWS.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[MyRow, MyCol].Value = myvalue;
                }
```

Please note that the QueryOutputWS reference, as well as MyRow, MyCol are specific to outputting the results decoded fields to a SpreadsheetGear worksheet - you can use any other output approach, including console outputs etc.

Comment: So what about all the help provided by the answer I gave? If what I provided resolved your problem based on the fact that your answer basically uses exactly what I provide, the norm is to accept the answer and vote it up is it was useful to you.

Comment: As I said in my reply to your post, it works perfectly - I didn't say thanks because there is a specific guideline not to. I hardly ever ask questions on this site, and I looked for ways to accept the answer and rate you, couldn't work that out - tell me how to do that, and I'll happily do it.

Comment: FYI, I didn't see your answer to the dimension issue, (only saw it now), worked it out myself - based on how you'd helped solve the prior issue (extension), which I'm very grateful for. Let's be clear - I didn't post the answer as my own work because I saw your reply - I only posted because I wanted to help others just as you helped me.

Comment: Easy misunderstanding. It was not meant to be confrontational. That happens on this site a lot. My statement may have been misinterpreted. No worries. Happy coding.

Comment: You are very generous. I worked out how to flag your answer as correct, vote it up, and also for your comments. As far as I can tell, you should now have those scores.